# Using a push button to switch between a stacked tab in python using PyQt

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am writing a program that requires a user switch from a page to another with a push button (using next and previous buttons). How do I connect the push button to the next page.

Comment: Have you got any code to demonstrate what you've tried. Producing a minimal example often leads you to the answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the simpliest way is to subclass `QStackedWidget` like this:

```
class MyStackWidget(QtGui.QStackedWidget):

    def forward(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() + 1)

    def backward(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex() - 1)
```

and then use it like this:

```
class MyWin(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stack = MyStackWidget(self)
        ...
        self.btnBackward.clicked.connect(self.stack.backward)
        self.btnForward.clicked.connect(self.stack.forward)
```